# Accessing files across a shared directory using a Windows service

Tags: windows, sharepoint, service, share, unc

I am trying to access files on a shared directory (sharepoint): `\\sitename\sites\Path_to_doc\doc.csv`

So I have this custom application that looks at files on that shared drive and when I launch the application by going to the folder where it's installed - `C:\myapp.exe,`

the **application can access them**. But when its *corresponding service is launched* from **services.msc** as the same user who launched the executable in the previous step, it doesn't find any files on the shared directory.

I guess, my question is:

what are the general differences to launching an application interactively by double clicking it versus launching the executable using a service and all of this with respect to Windows permissions and remote shared folders?

Comment: The only difference I can think of is that the service can only connect using the user's own account, whereas interactive programs can use saved credentials.  But you should also double-check that the service process really is running in the right account, e.g., using Process Explorer.